# Using templates as a function argument

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to convert my code to use templates so I can pass any type to it. I'm learning C++ from java so I'm not sure how to do it the c++ way. I'm getting an undeclared identifier error. Ill just show a small portion of the code. I want my function to accept any type of input. In Java I would just use generics.

```
class LList
{

private:

    template <typename T> struct ListItem
    {
        T item;
        ListItem* next;
    };

    int size;
    ListItem<int> *head;



public:

  void AddFront(ListItem<T> i) //This is the error
    {
        ListItem<T> *li = new ListItem<T>;
        li->item = i;
        li->next = head;
        head = li;
        ++size;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a `template <typename T>` for `AddFront` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following edits fix your issue. **Note:** if this is just for learning so be it but otherwise you should probably be using standard containers (e.g., `std::vector<T>`, `std::list<T>`, etc).

```
template<typename T> // Added
class LList
{
private:
    struct ListItem
    {
        T item;
        ListItem* next;
    };

    int size; // This should probably be 'size_t'
    // ListItem<int> *head; // <- Why did you hard-code to 'int'?
    ListItem *head;

public:
    // void AddFront(ListItem<T> i) //This is the error
    void AddFront(T i)
    {
        ListItem *li = new ListItem;
        li->item = i;
        li->next = head;
        head = li;
        ++size;
    }
}
```

Comment: By adding the template<typename T> to the class definition I get an error "Declaration of T shadows template parameter" on the line that declares my struct with typename t.

Comment: I missed that (but it should be removed).

Answer (score 0):

Your class `List` doesn't have any template parameter and can only work with list items if type `ListItem<int>`, because that's what the `head` can point to. If you want a generic `List`, it has to be a template.

When you make `List` a template, things inside `List` should not be explicitly templates any more because they are implicitly templates, as members of a class template.

```
template <typename T> // <-- add
class LList
{

private:

    // template <typename T> <-- remove, not needed
    struct ListItem
    {
        T item;
        ListItem* next;
    };

    int size;
    ListItem *head; // <--- No <T>, no <int>



public:

  void AddFront(ListItem i) // <--- No <T>
    {
        ListItem *li = new ListItem; // <--- No <T>
        li->item = i;
        li->next = head;
        head = li;
        ++size;
    }
};
```

Note that your *public* `AddFront` takes a *private* `ListItem` argument. You will not be able to call it as is from the outside unless you get a `ListItem` object from somewhere.